# how to parse different xml data in single retrofit call

Tags: android, retrofit, simple-xml-converter

I am using simplxmlconvertor with retrofit in my app to parse xml response from API. Success response from API is given below.

```
<Success>
  <id>sf98hjf</id>
</Success>
```

And error response is given below.

```
<Error>
  <message>No data found</message>
</Error>
```

My model class to parse success response is given below

```
 @Root(name = "Success")
public class ResponseModel {
@Element
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

This works fine when I get success response. But I want to parse error response as well to show error message to user. How can I achieve the same. Now I am getting exception since the structure doesn't match. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can do it with xml but with GSON you can define custom serializers. I guess you can do it with simplexmlconverter as well. I would use http code response to understand if you need a standard response serializer (code 200) or a error response serializer (code >=400) but it depends on the implementation of your api

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I have seen Response Interceptors for Retrofit. But my issue is I will be getting status code as 200 even though the response is error. So i cannot differentiate using that.

Comment: Can't you get the response as String and use instanceof operator to detect if it's a "standard" response or an error?

Comment: Then I will have to do manual parsing right?

Comment: From Simple documentation, I see that you can use serializer.read method to parse your string source on your Java POJO class http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#start. Take a look to "Deserializing a simple object". Let me know if this helps, in that case maybe we can think to write down an organized response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found one solution for my question. Instead of trying to parse with 2 different models, I intercepted the response and added a common root element. Then made Success and Error nodes as optional. So whether the response is success or Error the same model will parse it. Code is given below.

```
public class XmlInterceptor implements Interceptor {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        ResponseBody body = response.body();
        String wrappedBody = "<Response>" + body.string() + "</Response>";
        return response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(body.contentType(), wrappedBody))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Model class to parse response.

```
@Root(name = "Response")
public class UploadResponseModel {
@Element(required = false)
private UploadSuccessModel Success;
@Element(required = false)
private ErrorModel Error;

public UploadSuccessModel getSuccess() {
    return Success;
}

public void setSuccess(UploadSuccessModel success) {
    Success = success;
}

public ErrorModel getError() {
    return Error;
}

public void setError(ErrorModel error) {
    Error = error;
}
}
```